# Can Kruskal's and Prim's algorithm give trees with different weight?

Tags: graph-theory, trees, discrete-optimization

So, I have to find the minimal spanning tree in the graph in the picture. Below are my results. I feel like I shouldn't get 2 different weights, but I can't find a mistake.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn’t carry out Prim’s algorithm correctly. I’m assuming that you started with $v_1$, added the edge to $v_2$, and then added the edge from $v_2$ to $v_3$. That much is fine, but then you added the edge from $v_3$ to $v_5$, when you should have added the edge from $v_2$ to $v_5$: of all of the edges between the partial tree that you’d constructed up to that point and the other vertices of the graph, the one between $v_2$ and $v_5$ has the lowest weight. Specifically, the edges available for adding at that point, with their weights, are as follows, with the edge of lowest weight shown in red:

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
\text{Edge}&\text{Weight}\\\hline
v_1v_4&11\\
v_1v_5&9\\
v_2v_4&9\\
\color{red}{v_2v_5}&\color{red}8\\
v_3v_5&10
\end{array}$$

At each stage you should add the edge of lowest weight between **any** vertex of the partial tree that you’ve constructed up to that point and **any** vertex not in that partial tree.